Challenges with Formatting Kusto query Dataview output in Powershell
I have a RunKQLQuery.psm1 file where I follow all the steps from the Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/powershell/powershell?tabs=user
In here, I authenticate as an application and run the query and display the results:
$reader = $queryProvider.ExecuteQuery($query, $crp)

$dataTable = [Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Data.ExtendedDataReader]::ToDataSet($reader).Tables[0]
$dataView = New-Object System.Data.DataView($dataTable)
$dataView | Sort StartTime -Descending | Format-Table -AutoSize

return $dataView (or $datatable)

This part works fine.

Next, I have an Azure Function that calls the above .psm1 file and runs the query by doing:
$query = 'SignInLogs
    | take 5
    | evaluate bag_unpack(Location)
    | project 
        CreatedDateTime,
        IPAddress,
        UserPrincipalName,
        ResourceDisplayName,
        CountryOrRegion,
        ResourceTenantId
    $data = Run-KQLQuery -query $query -tenantId $TenantId

Unfortunately, I am unable to use the $data output since I can't get it formatted in a nice way.
foreach ($row in $data){
        Write-Output "Row content: $($row)"
    }


When I check the data type of $dataView before being returned, I can see that it's: System.Data.DataTable
And when checking the type in my Azure Function, it's System.Object[].
I experimented with the suggested solution of converting the results to a JSON string, but it appears to break the output I receive in my Azure Function. Details of this approach I attempted: Unable to display Data View result in Power shell
When printing $data after applying the solution from the post I get the following output:
Kusto.Data, Version=12.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=829a00acde12d551 Kusto.Data.Data.Impl.Impl.KustoJsonDataStreamReader Data type after conversion: Kusto.Data.Data.Impl.Impl.KustoJsonDataStreamReader Number of rows in table: 0

In addition, I tried the solution from How to return specific data type from PowerShell function i.e. DataTable where return is replaced with write-output -noenumerate. However, the output still seems unusable in my Azure Function.
My objective is to execute the query using the following command:
$data = Run-KQLQuery -query $query -tenantId $TenantId

In the module file, it will handle the authentication and execute the query. Subsequently, in my Azure Function, I intend to retrieve the data and utilize it for the remainder of my code to trigger an event with some fields like IP/User/Date. What would be the best approach for this?

Remove this line from your first sample - $dataView | Sort StartTime -Descending | Format-Table -AutoSize - it’s converting $dataview into internal “display formatting instructions” which get rendered to the console when you run  it interactively, but are being returned along with the output from return $dataView in your live environment. These formatting instructions are causing the …Format.FormatStartData etc lines in your logs…

@mclayton I really appreciate the response. I have tried this, but unfortunately, it doesn't really change anything in the output for me.
